# Best way to calculate min, max and average input values, without knowing quantity entered?

Tags: java, arraylist, max, average, min

I need to add code to find the min, max and avg of the numbers entered.
Is it best to use an arraylist  ?

Thank you for the advice. Glad to hear I'll learn about array lists in the future(because I'm totally unfamiliar with them now), and stick to the advice given. Thanks again.

Comment: "Best" in what sense? What have you tried? What's the specific issue(s) you're having?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to calculate it manually (i.e. this isn't a homework assignment) then you can use the built in statistical functions:

```
DoubleStream.generate(input::nextDouble).takeWhile(v -> v != 999).summaryStatistics();
```

That will give you min, max, count, average and sum without you having to do any manual calculations at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve without ArrayList too.
Need to use MIN, MAX, SUM and COUNTER variable and initialize MIN and MAX with first user input.

When user input any value then check with MIN, MAX and add it to SUM.

You can have login to calculate average outer side of loop(SUM/COUNTER)

Comment: @CouponCode If its helpful then upvote/accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to calculate it manually (for the purposes of understanding how it works), all you need to do is (in pseudo-code form):

```
// NOTE: this is pseudo-code only, not executable code!

// start with the min set to the largest float
float min = Float.MAX_VALUE;

// start with the max set to the smallest float
float max = Float.MIN_VALUE;

// start with an average of 0 and count of 0
float average = 0.0;
int count = 0;

// for each value input
{

    // get the value from the user
    float nextValue = getValueFromUser(...);

    // update the min value
    if (nextValue < min) {
        min = nextValue;
    }

    // update the max value
    if (nextValue > max) {
        max = nextValue;
    }

    // recalculate the average
    float sum = average * count;
    count++;
    sum += nextValue;
    average = sum / count;

} // loop until the user is done

// print the min, max and average
```

Comment: Average should be calculate after loop termination.

Comment: Yes, it would be more efficient, but this shows that you can do it on the fly if you need to.